# Failed to insert record and return id

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query that returns its id after adding

```
DO
    $do$    
        BEGIN
            IF (SELECT COUNT(*) = 0 FROM COMMENTS WHERE PARENT_ID = ''${this.parent_id}') THEN 
                UPDATE COMMENTS SET HAS_CHILD = TRUE WHERE COMMENT_ID = '${this.parent_id}';
            END IF;
                INSERT INTO COMMENTS(USER_ID, ... , PARENT_ID,  ... , HAS_CHILD) VALUES('${this.user_id}', ... , ${this.parent_id}, ... ', FALSE)
                RETURNING COMMENT_ID;
        END
    $do$
```

When executing the request, an error occurs: `ERROR:  query has no destination for result data
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 3 at SQL statement
SQL state: 42601`. The request is successful without `RETURNING COMMENT_ID;`.

Why the request is not executed with `RETURNING COMMENT_ID;`?

Comment: A `do` block can not return a value.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `IF exists (SELECT * FROM COMMENTS WHERE ...)` would be more efficient than counting all rows

Comment: "UPDATE comments SET has_child=true WHERE has_child=false and comment_id=12345" should be even more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PL/pgSQL returning values have to be assigned to a variable with the keyword `INTO`, see:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW

```
DO
  $do$
    DECLARE
      result INTEGER := 0;
    BEGIN
      IF (SELECT COUNT(*) = 0 FROM COMMENTS WHERE PARENT_ID = '${this.parent_id}') THEN 
        UPDATE COMMENTS SET HAS_CHILD = TRUE WHERE COMMENT_ID = '${this.parent_id}';
        -- Here you could specify returning value for the UPDATE branch...
      END IF;
      INSERT INTO COMMENTS(USER_ID, ... , PARENT_ID,  ... , HAS_CHILD) VALUES('${this.user_id}', ... , ${this.parent_id}, ... ', FALSE)
        RETURNING COMMENT_ID INTO result;
      RETURN result;
    END
$do$
```

### Edit

Or you could use the `RETURN QUERY` syntax:

```
DO
  $do$
    BEGIN
      IF (SELECT COUNT(*) = 0 FROM COMMENTS WHERE PARENT_ID = '${this.parent_id}') THEN 
        UPDATE COMMENTS SET HAS_CHILD = TRUE WHERE COMMENT_ID = '${this.parent_id}';
        -- Here you could specify returning value for the UPDATE branch...
      END IF;
      RETURN QUERY
        INSERT INTO COMMENTS(USER_ID, ... , PARENT_ID,  ... , HAS_CHILD) VALUES('${this.user_id}', ... , ${this.parent_id}, ... ', FALSE)
          RETURNING COMMENT_ID;
    END
$do$
```